# Problem with \widehat in the package yhmath

Tags: yhmath

`\widehat` has a strange behavior when the package `yhmath` is loaded. In particular, when I compile the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
$\widehat{C(,c)}$
$\widehat{C(x,c)}$
\end{document}
```

everything's fine for the first `widehat` expression, but for the second, there is a right parentheses after the hat.

[image]

Is there an error in the code or is there another way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get no extra bracket if I run your document with texlive 2013

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeX Maker. Is it the reason for this strange behavior...

Comment: I too don't get any misplaced parenthesis. I can reproduce the output only by adding `\mathchar"300` before the closing `$`. Try updating `yhmath`.

Comment: Thank you egreg! I updated all the packages and now it works fine.

Comment: due to old package, fixed by update