# $\widehat$ prints a reverse paranthesis whenever argument length >5

Tags: macros

I am using Babel Greek and the following code for my doc:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[vcentering,dvips,hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\geometry{
papersize={210mm,280mm},
total={150mm,240mm},
includehead
%%%%includefoot
}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{yhmath} %<-package for $\widehat$
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\huge}
\usepackage{grmath}  %transforms \cos->\συν, etc.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\usepackage{mystyle}   % here my definitions ... newcommand ... etc.
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{{Κεφάλαιο }\thechapter.\ \ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{} % Clear all footer fields 

}

\begin{document}
Η γωνία \wdh{A'O'Y''} παρουσιάζει πρόβλημα.

\wdh{AOY''}

\wdh{B'OX''}

\wdh{BOX}

\end{document}
```

I have included my header code as I use it. Here's the output:

[image]

Does anybody know why the output for $\widehat$ is corrupted with a parenthesis?

The macro definition I use for $\wdh$ is:

```
\newcommand{\wdh}[1]{$\widehat{#1}$}
```

and the command widehat I think comes from the yhmath package.

The problem occurs even if I use the plain command $\widehat{AO'Y''}$, etc.

Comment: You don't need `yhmath` to use `\widehat`. Why are you loading it?

Comment: My mistake, I think it's for something else. $\wideparen$, etc (for arcs).

Comment: This is probably due to an outdated version of `yhmath` (and the font information), see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149216/problem-with-widehat-in-the-package-yhmath

Comment: @Sigur `yhmath` provides wider hats than the default fonts.

Comment: Thanks. I will update the \yhmath package and see if it gets better.

Comment: OK, \yhmath is causing it. Problem disappears if \yhmath is not loaded, but I need it for \wideparen. I tried uninstalling and installing \yhmath to update, same problem.

Comment: Assume `\wdh{A'O'Y''}` is `$\widehat{A'O'Y''}$`, my machine gives me the desired result of hats. (However the greek characters outside are not well-displayed.) Please cut down your example and make it self-contained.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to an outdated version of yhmath and is not reproducible with an up-to-date TeX distribution