# Problems with \wideparen

Tags: yhmath

I am using `\wideparen` from the `yhmath` package to indicate arcs. Now I have encountered problems with the following symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
$\wideparen{\gamma(t_1)\gamma(s_1)}$
$\wideparen{\tilde{q} q'}$
\end{document}
```

The first gives me an additional bracket floating on the low right. A similar question was asked here: [Problem with \widehat in the package yhmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149216/problem-with-widehat-in-the-package-yhmath) but apparently was fixed by a package update at that time...

The second command seems to move the first q almost completely over the second.

Any suggestions, how I could still get the desired output?

Comment: I just downloaded the package, and have no problem with the first construct.  For the second, a workaround is this: `\setbox0=\hbox{${\tilde{q} q'}$}$\wideparen{\box0}$`

Comment: If you don't need it to work in smaller math styles, then this in your preamble: `\let\svwideparen\wideparen
\renewcommand\wideparen[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{${#1}$}\svwideparen{\box0}}`.  If you **DO** need it to work in smaller math styles, then this: `\usepackage{yhmath,scalerel}
\let\svwideparen\wideparen
\renewcommand\wideparen[1]{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{${\SavedStyle#1}$}\svwideparen{\box0}}}`

Answer (score 4):

Normal problem with nested accents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\makeatletter
\let\yhmath@wideparen\wideparen
\DeclareRobustCommand{\wideparen}[1]{{\mathpalette\inner@wideparen{#1}}}
\newcommand\inner@wideparen[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$#1\m@th#2$}%
  \yhmath@wideparen{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$\wideparen{\gamma(t_1)\gamma(s_1)}$
$\wideparen{{\tilde{q} q'}}_{\wideparen{\tilde{q}q'}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]